# Play Framework 2.6 and bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, playframework, bootstrap-4, playframework-2.6

I have an issue with adding Bootstrap to my play project.
i have downloaded the source for Bootstrap 4 and added the css and js files to the project.

```html
@*
* This template is called from the `index` template. This template
* handles the rendering of the page header and body tags. It takes
* two arguments, a `String` for the title of the page and an `Html`
* object to insert into the body of the page.
*@
@(title: String)(content: Html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    @* Here's where we render the page title `String`. *@
    <title>@title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css")">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/Blackweb.jpg")">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
</body>
@* And here's where we render the `Html` object containing
* the page content. *@
@content
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js")"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

However when i run and open the page on local host the toggle icon that should appear when the screen size has been reduced does not appear.the outline appear but no icon.
Any ideas why or easier approaches for integrating bootstrap 4 into a play framework project.Here is my issue below
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bootstrap code is correct. The example works in the fiddle, this means that the problem exactly with the icon loading on play framework.

You did not mention any errors, but, it looks like a problem with content security policies. The Play 2.6 has the `contentSecurityPolicy` enabled by default, and the Bootstrap 4 toggle icon has the source of `img data`:

```
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 30 30' xmlns='http://ww…p='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3E%3C/svg%3E);
}
```

So you need to have at least `img-src 'self' data: *` in the security policies to show the image with the data source.

```
play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy = "default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data: *"
```

Or you can just switch it off:

```
play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy=null
```

More information:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26#securityheadersfilter
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SecurityHeaders
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/

Comment: Thank You,It was exactly as described trying to get back into using play framework after studying it for a short time in college and jumping too far ahead.